# Flutter SharedPreferences getBool function returns null

Tags: flutter, dart, sharedpreferences

I have the class below which I set and get the bool value to remember the user and auto-login next time.

```
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';

class SettingHelper {
  static Future<bool> getValue(String key) async {
    final SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    var s = prefs.getBool(key);
    print("GetValue ${s.toString()}"); //prints "GetValue true"
    return s;
  }

  static Future<void> setValue(String key, bool value) async {
    final SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    prefs.setBool(key, value);
  }
}
```

I set my value in Login page with a CheckBox value.

```
onPressed: () {
...
SettingHelper.setValue("rememberMe", checkBoxValue);
...
}
```

When I start debugging I saw setValue worked. 
But when I hot restart getValue returns null in initState() but returns true in function. Here is the code:

```
class LandingPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _LandingPageState createState() => _LandingPageState();
}

class _LandingPageState extends State<LandingPage> {
  bool rememberMe;

  void _getRememberMeChoice() async {
    rememberMe = await SettingHelper.getValue("rememberMe");
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _getRememberMeChoice();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print(rememberMe);  //Returns null
    if (rememberMe == true) {
      return BridgeList();
    } else
      return LoginScreen();
  }
}
```

These are the outputs:

```
I/flutter (11724): null
I/flutter (11724): GetValue true
```

Please tell me if I'm doing something wrong...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because you can't await a value inside `initState()`

In this case the `build()` function is executed before you get the `rememberMe` value.

Try adding a `setState((){})` after the `getValue()`, so you do a rebuild.

Like this

```
void _getRememberMeChoice() async {
    rememberMe = await SettingHelper.getValue("rememberMe");
    setState((){})
  }
```

Also, notice that in the first `build` execution, the `rememberMe` value **will** be `null`. So you should add that validation in your `if` condition.